# Distributed plugin - add support for Cyrillic

Tags: database, language

Our plugin creates a custom database table for storing text entered into a textarea.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    id          MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    component   VARCHAR( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    user_id     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    target_id   BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date        INT( 15 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    feedback    VARCHAR( 10000 ) NOT NULL
    );";
```

How do we add support for Cyrillic in the feedback field?  We have no control over the database collation or WP settings.  Would setting the feedback field to `NVARCHAR` solve it or would that create other problems?

Comment: possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar#147302 however I'm unsure what makes this question WordPress specific, it should be possible to answer this on stackoverflow with zero WP knowledge if the answerer is familiar with MariaDB/MySQL